# Parse XML SOAP to Object JSON with PHP 7

Tags: php, json, xml, soap

I have the following problem, I need to transform the SOAP response from $ response = $ client -> __ getLastResponse (); And transform into a JSON object. Here is the image of the response I get in PHP with the above method.

**stdClass return for $result:**

```
stdClass Object ( [RealizarConsultaSQLResult] => AEC4 - AEC7 - )
```

Response SOAP:

```
<NewDataSet><Resultado> <CODTURMA>AEC4</CODTURMA><NOME>-</NOME></Resultado><Resultado><CODTURMA>AEC7</CODTURMA><NOME>-</NOME> 
</Resultado></NewDataSet>
```

**Observation: My code works normally, just need to receive the answer in the format below: (expected output):**

```
{
  "NewDataSet": {
    "Resultado": [
      {
        "CODTURMA": "AEC4",
        "NOME": "-"
      },
      {
        "CODTURMA": "AEC7",
        "NOME": "-"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

**My Code**

```
   <?php
    require("wsdls.php");
    //Cabeçalho de autenticação básica no SOAP
    $soapParams = array('login' => $usuario,
                     'password' => base64_decode($pass),
               'authentication' => SOAP_AUTHENTICATION_BASIC,
                        'trace' => 1,
                   'exceptions' => 0
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($WsdlRMSQL, $soapParams); 
    $params = array('codSentenca' => 'TOTVS.MDA.402', 'codColigada'=>'1', 'codSistema'=>'S','parameters'=>'CODCOLIGADA=1;CODFILIAL=1;IDPERLET=2;IDHABILITACAOFILIAL=10');

    //Resultado do Webservice
    $result = $client->realizarConsultaSQL($params);

    //Resposta do SOAP
    $response = $client->__getLastResponse();
    //$xmlString = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $response);
    //var_dump($response);
    print_r($response);


    ?>
```

[Image form SOAP response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvs27.png)

Comment: Share response string instead of image and also your expected output you want to extract.

Comment: Don't post image of strings, write the string in your question.

Comment: Response: <NewDataSet> <Resultado> <CODTURMA>AEC4</CODTURMA> <NOME>-</NOME> </Resultado> <Resultado> <CODTURMA>AEC7</CODTURMA> <NOME>-</NOME> </Resultado> </NewDataSet>

Comment: Can you share which information you want to extract from this response?

Comment: Sahil, 

{
  "NewDataSet": {
    "Resultado": [
      {
        "CODTURMA": "AEC4",
        "NOME": "-"
      },
      {
        "CODTURMA": "AEC7",
        "NOME": "-"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
try{    
    $xml = $client->__getLastResponse();
    // SimpleXML seems to have problems with the colon ":" in the <xxx:yyy> response tags, so take them out

    $xml = preg_replace("/(<\/?)(\w+):([^>]*>)/", "$1$2$3", $xml);
    $xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
    $json = json_encode($xml);
    $responseArray = json_decode($json,true);

    // dd($responseArray['soapenvHeader']['headResponseHeader']['headStatusMessages']['headMessageDescription']);

    Log::info("bill payment response".json_encode($result));
    Log::info("bill payment response xml".$client->__getLastResponse());

    if(!empty($responseArray['soapenvBody'])):
        return redirect()->back()->with('status', $responseArray['soapenvHeader']['headResponseHeader']['headStatusMessages']['headMessageDescription']);
    else:
        return redirect()->back()->with('err', "We could not complete your request, please try again");
    endif;

} catch (\SoapFault $fault) {
    Log::info("bill payment error".json_encode($fault));
    return redirect()->back()->with('err', $fault->getMessage());
}
```